# swap ( twist ) multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

i want to "twist" a 2d array by "90°"..

let me explain that.

I have an array like this:

```
array(
    array( adam , brad , chris , david ),
    array( 21   , 23   , 22    , 26    )
)
```

and i want to convert that into something like this:

```
array(
    array( adam  , 21 ),
    array( brad  , 23 ),
    array( chris , 22 ),
    array( david , 26 )
)
```

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
// Your array stored as $arr

$newArr = array();
for ($i = 0;$i < count($arr[0]); $i++) {
    $newArr[] = array($arr[0][$i],$arr[1][$i]);
}
```

EDIT: You tag sorting, but the array is already sorted, do you want sorting too?

Comment: Slight micro optimization here, shift the count($arr[0]) outside the loop to stop it counting every iteration, nice answer though gets my +1

Comment: @Dale: You're right, but in this case it would be so micro-micro that it would not make any difference. `for` is still a lot faster than `foreach`.

Comment: thank you men, thats exactly what i've did just befor the first answer was posted.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'd throw a foreach out there:

```
$array = array(
    array('adam', 'brad', 'chris', 'david'),
    array(21, 23, 22, 26)
);

$final_array = array();
foreach ($array[0] as $k => $v)
{
    $final_array[] = array($array[0][$k], $array[1][$k]);
}

print_r($final_array);
```

After some confusion in the comments to this it has been pointed out that you can shrink the code to this:

```
foreach ($array[0] as $k => $v)
{
    $final_array[] = array($v, $array[1][$k]);
}
```

Thanks Stan

Comment: `$array[0][$k]` is `$v`. Code can be simplified.

Comment: @Stan no.. $array[0][$k] is 0 or 1 or 2... $v is adam, brad or blah blah

Comment: thx men, that was what i'm looking for. just a second ago i've did the same with just a for loop and using `$array[0][$i]`

Comment: @Dale, you're wrong. If `$array[0][$k]` would be 0, 1, 2, your code would not do what's expected (just read your source carefully, you placed `$array[0][$k]` into first dimention of the resulting array, so it must contain names, and it does). It works properly exactly because `$array[0][$k]` is `$v`, that is names.

Comment: @Stan Do you know what `foreach ($array as $k => $v)` actually does? Feel free to copy and paste this whole answer into a page and run the code.

Comment: @Dale, you don't see my point. I know `foreach` pretty well. I just wanted to let you know that the code can be simplified by replacing the line `$final_array[] = array($array[0][$k], $array[1][$k]);` with `$final_array[] = array($v, $array[1][$k]);`. Period.

Comment: @Stan I didn't see your point at all, though you didn't make it very clearly :)

Comment: @Dale, I don't know how to phrase this more clearly. The line I've mentioned above is just inefficient. I suggested how to change it to make more efficient.

Comment: guys, i've marked this as answer because of the general idea, i've used for-loop, see my update.. thanks anyway

Comment: @Stan it was this that threw me off "you're wrong. If $array[0][$k] would be 0, 1, 2, your code would not do what's expected".. It's exactly because they are that that the code works, I didn't get your point at all, my bad, I have updated the answer

Comment: @Dale, heh, you're wrong again ;-). You have just replaced `$array[0][$k]` with `$v`, so again `$array[0][$k]` is `$v`, that is names, and not 0, 1, 2... This is the $k what is 0, 1, 2...

Comment: @Stan No $array[0][$k] is like $array[0][0] not $array[0]['dave'] I don't understand what you're trying to say :)

Comment: @Dale, exactly. This is why `$array[0][$k]` is not 0, 1, 2. `$k` is 0, 1, 2.

Comment: @Stan I give up talking to you now, I'm going to go listen to paint dry

Answer (score 1):

Here's one for associative arrays (which are a kind of 2d array):

```
// Take array like ([0] => ('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'), [1] => ('key1' => 'value45', 'key2' => 'value3'))
// and transform it to like ('key1' => ([0] => 'value1', [1] => 'value45'), 'key2' => ([0] => 'value2', [1] => 'value3'))
function array_twist(array $array) {
    $number_of_rows = count($array);
    $twisted_array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_rows; ++$i) {
        $fields = array_keys($array[$i]);
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $data = $array[$i][$field];
            if ($data != '') {
                $twisted_array[$field][] = $data;
            }
         }
     }
   return $twisted_array;
}
```